# Symmetric Matrices Using Pythagorean Triples

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find symmetric matrices A =$\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\   c&d 
> \end{pmatrix}$ such that $A^{2}=I_{2}$.

Alright, so I've posed this problem earlier but my question is in regard to this problem.

I was told that $\frac{1}{t}\begin{pmatrix}\mp r & \mp s \\   \mp s & \pm r  \end{pmatrix}$ is a valid matrix $A$ as $A^{2}=I_{2}$, given the condition that $r^{2}+s^{2}=t^{2}$, that is, (r,s,t) is a Pythagorean Triple.

Does anybody know why this works?

Comment: are you asking why the condition that $(r,s,t)$ be a Pythagorean triple is necessary for this matrix to satisfy $A^2 = I_2$.

Comment: No, A does not necessarily have to be a Pythagorean triple in order to produce $I_{2}$, such as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$. I'm asking why does the Pythagorean triple work? Is there a reason?

EDIT: I apologize; I think I misread your comment. Yes, I want to know why (r,s,t) as a Pythagorean triple works.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! If you move your comment to the answer section, I'll be happy to award the top answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because $$A^2 = \frac{1}{t^2}\begin{pmatrix}r & s\\s & -r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\s&-r\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{t^2}\begin{pmatrix}r^2+s^2 & 0\\0 & r^2 + s^2\end{pmatrix}.$$
and you want the diagonals to be 1, i.e. $\frac{r^2 + s^2}{t^2} = 1$.